# Why does \relsize{-1} in normal size not result in \smaller?

Tags: fontsize

This is maybe just me being unable to find the corresponding part of the manual, but I'd expect `relsize`'s `\smaller` or `\relsize{-1}` to have the same effect as using `\small` inside normal-sized text. However, both seem to result in the equivalent of `\footnotesize`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}

    \texttt{\small k1}: \texttt{\smaller k1} \textsmaller{\texttt{k1}} \texttt{\relsize{-1} k1} \texttt{\relsize{0} k1} \texttt{\footnotesize k1}

\end{document}
```

Result, where I'd expect all but the last two (which I included only for comparison) to be the same size:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `\relsize{-1}` command takes the current size and divides it by 1.2; then the nearest available font size is chosen. Since 10/1.2=8.33333, eight point size (that is `\footnotesize`) is picked up.

You can do, as explained in the package documentation, `\relsize{-0.5}`, in order to get nine point size when the current size is ten point.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! Just out of curiosity, is there a way to really replicate the one-step-smaller behavior without knowing the specific font sizes?

Comment: @rainer -- possibly not useful for you, but `amsart` and other ams document classes define `\smaller` and `\larger` to take an optional argument that proceeds using the "defined" sizes, so `\smaller[1]` steps down from 10 to 9pt (one size), `\larger[2]` steps up from 10 to 12pt (two sizes), etc.  `relsize` also allows use of the optional argument, but the progression is different, as pointed out by egreg.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It's a pity that Leslie didn't think to parameterize the predefined font sizes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, but as you guessed, I have to use a different document class.